UPDATE CASE usage where the fields to be updated are different for each row
CONTEXT:
I have a mysql version 8 table as follows.
id  |   field1  | field2    |   ...... | field10    | timeStamp
_______________________________________________________________

fieldN are float datatype. id is unique, and indexed. The values that need to go into this table are being generated by different distributed program nodes on a network. Different nodes produce data for one or more fields. Altogether, I have around 35000 nodes generating data every minute, so that is about 600 inputs per second.
(Note: it was a much smaller set of nodes in the beginning, slowly kept growing). Currently, for each request coming from the node, I run an UPDATE query something like this.
Node 1 eg: UPDATE table set field1=24.5, field6=44.6,timeStamp=now() where id=1
Node 2 eg: UPDATE table set field3=53.3, field9=4.2, field10=98.8, timeStamp=now() where id=2
Node 3 eg: UPDATE table set field1=55.5, field8=7.2, field9=8.8, timeStamp=now() where id=3

etc. So, which fields/ # of fields being updated depends on any given node, as shown above. Some may have data for 2 fields, some just 1, some even 5 or 6, etc.
TASK AT HAND:
To reduce the number of db connectons/ queries (currently one per each node per minute), I am putting things together to use Kafka to collect all these updates, and then run them in batches instead of individual queries.
Once the data from various nodes are in kafka, This is where I am not sure what is the best way to proceed. I did some reading, and came across the following options.
1. Transactions,
2. CASE
3. MultiQuery.

I use docker. I ran tests Based on the test script (https://github.com/yanxurui/keepcoding/blob/master/php/mysql/multiple_update.php), and found that that CASE method seems to be the fastest. While Multiquery seems to show the lowest time of execution with this test script, it looks like it is just dumping all those queries into mysql, and it takes much longer for mysql to actually finish the queries (as observed by info from docker stats). Whereas, the case method seems to be faster.
MY SOLUTION
After considering various approaches, here is what I am thinking.
UPDATE table set 
    field1= CASE    when id=1 THEN 24.5 
                    when id=3 THEN 55.5
                    else field1
            END,
    field3= CASE    when id=2 THEN 53.3
                    else field3
            END,
    etc..,
    timeStamp=now() 
    WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...)
    

Which means, For each field in the table, I have to iterate through the list of nodes to see if they have a value to report to that field, and so on.
QUESTIONS

Am I right in selecting the CASE method? Or did i miss anything in the tests I did?
If CASE method is the right way to go, is my solution the right way to frame the UPDATE Query?


It would be better to normalize the table so all the fieldN were different rows in another table, rather than separate columns.

When all the case clauses are comparing the same column, it's simpler to write CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 24.5 WHEN 3 THEN 55.5 ELSE field1 END

@Barmar you mean there should be individual tables for each of the 'fieldN' variables?

No, a single table with columns XXX_id (FK to this XXX table), field_num, and field_value. field_num would contain values from 1 to 10.

Then it just becomes UPDATE XXX_fields SET field_value = CASE WHEN XXX_id = 1 AND field_num = 1 THEN 24.5 ...

Have you tried something like this (with ON DUPLICATE KEY):
INSERT INTO table (id,field,field2,...,field10) VALUES 
(1, 24.5,null,null,null,..null),
(2, null,null,null,null,..98.8),
(3, 55.5,null,null,null,..8.8)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  field1=IF(VALUES(field1) = NULL, field1, VALUES(field1)), 
  field2=IF(VALUES(field2) = NULL, field2, VALUES(field2)),       ...
  field10=IF(VALUES(field10) = NULL, field10,  VALUES(field10)),
  `timestamp` = NOW();


IF() function needs in 3 arguments strictly. COALESCE() is more reasonable. But the technique itself is applicable.

@Akina - Ups, my mistake, i have change my answer

Note that in MySQL 8 this use of VALUES() is deprecated, you should use NEW.fieldN instead.

I meant to say similar/ better results compared to CASE approach

Save the data which must be used for UPDATE to temporary table of the same structure (if a column should be updated then it contains according value otherwise NULL). Then use
UPDATE maintable
  JOIN temptable USING (id)
  SET maintable.column1 = COALESCE(temptable.column1, maintable.column1),
--    ...
      maintable.column10 = COALESCE(temptable.column10, maintable.column10),
      `timestamp` = NOW();

Also I'd recommend you to alter the table, set ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP option to the timestamp column, and remove this column explicit updating from the query.

You mean, Run individual UPDATE queries to tempTable first? Would nt it still cause the same (or more interaction) with the DB? Also, yes to your timestamp comment, I only meant to show that there are other fields that are common to all nodes.

no, not individual updates to tempTable, have tempTable start empty, do a single insert inserting all the rows (or one insert per thousand rows or so).  then a single update

hmmm. will look into this. I did not know of this approach at all, but will read and try it out. Thanks,

@aVC Run individual UPDATE queries to tempTable first? No, of course. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SELECT. Or, if a pack of batches is executed in the same connection, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE then multiple INSERT/UPDATE/TRUNCATE.
